# Is there an R function for comparing rows in data.frame?

Tags: r

I summarized dataset and want to compare the rows with conditions. What functions can I use?

The dataset is from gapminder and I filtered it with two continents. Now I want to compare those rows by total_pop column and want to know in which year Africa has more total population than Europe. But I have no idea which functions can I use.

```
data <- gapminder %>% 
  filter(continent %in% c("Africa", "Europe")) %>% 
  group_by(continent, year) %>% 
  summarise(total_pop = sum(pop))
```

I expect the output of 1987, 1992, 1997, 2002, 2007

Comment: In general if your analysis involves comparing continents then you are better of having them in columns than rows i.e. convert your data to wide format and compare columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have same number of rows for `"Africa"` and `"Europe"` we can do

```
unique(data$year[data$total_pop[data$continent == "Africa"] > 
       data$total_pop[data$continent == "Europe"]])
#[1] 1987 1992 1997 2002 2007
```

Or explicitly doing

```
Africa_data <- data[data$continent == "Africa",]
Europe_data <- data[data$continent == "Europe",]
Africa_data$year[Africa_data$total_pop > Europe_data$total_pop]
#[1] 1987 1992 1997 2002 2007
```